# Thread doesn't work

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, game-physics

I've createad two Threads in java , with a while loop , but when I run the program only one Thread works , why? The principal problem is that I'm creating a flappy bird videogame and in a Thread I generate obstacoles and in another Thread I move the obstacoles.
[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I69adfEqwC0) there is an example of flappy bird game physics

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int altezza_frame = 900;
        int larghezza_frame  = 800;
        int gap = 150;
        int intervallo = 200;
        Vector <JLabel> alti = new Vector<JLabel>();
        Vector <JLabel> bassi = new Vector<JLabel>();
        JFrame pannello = new JFrame();
        Thread inizializza = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                pannello.setSize(larghezza_frame , altezza_frame);
                pannello.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                pannello.setLayout(null);
                pannello.setResizable(true);
                pannello.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("icona.png")));
                Color cielo = new Color(66, 203, 244);
                pannello.getContentPane().setBackground(cielo);
                pannello.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        Thread ostacoli = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Color verde = new Color(116, 181, 43);
                alti.setSize(1);
                bassi.setSize(1);
                int x = 0;
               while (true){
                    JLabel alto = new JLabel();
                    int altezza = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(100, 450 + 1);
                    alto.setSize(100, altezza);
                    alto.setOpaque(true);
                    alto.setBackground(verde);
                    alto.setLocation(x, 0);
                    JLabel basso = new JLabel();
                    basso.setSize(100, altezza_frame - altezza - gap);
                    basso.setOpaque(true);
                    basso.setBackground(verde);
                    basso.setLocation(x, altezza + gap);
                    pannello.add(basso);
                    pannello.add(alto);
                    alti.add(alto);
                    bassi.add(basso);
                    alti.setSize(alti.size()+1);
                    bassi.setSize(bassi.size()+1);
                    x+=(100+intervallo);
                }
            }
        };
        Thread muovi_ostacoli = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    for(int x=0;x<alti.size();x++){
                       System.out.print("ciao");
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        inizializza.run();
        ostacoli.run();
        muovi_ostacoli.start();
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Define "works."  What do you see happening, what do you expect to happen.

Comment: Don't use Threads. Use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to schedule the animation.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). Considering the amount of code you just posted, you may also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: markspace , Now it opens a jframe but it doesn't print the output. I want both actions to be done. Sorry for my english.

Comment: You're so fast wow!!! I  expected an answer after days , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.run()` to execute the Threads inizializza and ostacoli. This will not **start** them but will run them in the current thread. Use `.start()` to start the threads. see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start())

Comment: Correct for the usage of Threads (1+). However, Threads should not be used in the final solution. Updates to GUI components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread, which is why you should be using a Swing Timer.